# Firebase Cloud Storage Security Rules - Custom Claims are too long, so saving them as strings, but can't extract on Security Rules

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security

Since some members in our organization have their Custom Claims exceeding 1,000 characters, we started saving the claims as strings (Hopefully that's a right approach).

For example, if a user's groups would have been saved so far to the claims like this:
`{groups: ['G1', 'G2', 'G3']}` now we save like this `{groups: '|1|2|3'}`.
And then on the Security Rules, I'm trying to convert in the `storage.tmpl.rules` the string in to the array.

```
function hasGroup(group) {
    return isSignedIn() && getGroups().hasAny([group]);
    // Also tried: group in getGroups()
}

function getGroups() {
    // '|1|2|3' => ['', '1', '2', '3'] => '|G|G1|G2|G3' => ['', 'G1', 'G2', 'G3']
    return request.auth.token.groups.split('|').join('|G').split('|');
}

match /path/path/{groupId}/path/{allPaths=**} {
    allow write: hasGroup(groupId);
}
```

I keep getting denied! What am I missing? Also, there are no resources on the web on practices to minimize claims size. AND also you can't debug that in the simulator. Thank you for reading, any help would help.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to exceed the size limits of custom claims, the first thing you should consider is not using custom claims.  Instead, you can store per-user data in a document identified by the user's UID, and [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) that document to check its fields in security rules.  Clear examples can be found in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).  For example:

> ```
> // Allow the user to delete cities if their user document has the
> // 'admin' field set to 'true'
> allow delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
> ```

Before you raise an objection about requiring the cost of a document read, I'll point out that custom claims are inherently limited, and can not scale at all. This is one of the main reasons that security rules allow reading of documents with much larger capacity.  When applications need to scale beyond simple use cases, costs are unvoidable.

You should have additional rules that restrict write access to the documents that you use to store per-user permissions, as users should probably not be able to write the documents that determine access to other resources.

Comment: That might work on Firestore rules but I'm trying to dictate access to storage resources.

Comment: Then you should probably edit your question to remove "Firestore" and change it to "Cloud Storage".  They are completely different products, even though they sare the same syntax for rules.

Comment: Updated The topic to refer to Storage. Any help would be appreciated.